# Fail to pass multiple arguments to a python script in command line

Tags: python, bash

I was trying to write a python script like this:

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[2]
```

Let's call it `arg.py`, and run it in command line:

```
python arg.py one two
```

it printed: one two.

Everything was fine.

Then I wanted it to be handy so I put arg.py in my `$PATH` and gave it permission to exacuate so wherever I'm I can simply type `arg` in command line to run this script. I tried

```
arg one two
```

but it failed. The exception said:"bash: test: one: unary operator expected". But if I just do

```
arg one
```

it worked fine.

My question is: why I can't pass multiple arguments like this? And what is the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: How have you added the script to your path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably named your script `test`, which is a Bash builtin name. Name it something else.

```
$ help test
test: test [expr]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    Exits with a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false) depending on
    the evaluation of EXPR.  Expressions may be unary or binary.  Unary
    expressions are often used to examine the status of a file.  There
    are string operators and numeric comparison operators as well.

    The behavior of test depends on the number of arguments.  Read the
    bash manual page for the complete specification.

    ...
```

That's why you're getting the error from `bash`:

```
bash: test: one: unary operator expected
                   ^--------- because it expects an operator to go before 'two'
             ^-------- and test doesn't like the argument 'one' you've provided
       ^-------- because it's interpreting your command as the builtin 'test'
  ^--- Bash is giving you an error
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks! I didn't know "test" was a bash builtin.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse command line arguments in Python using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) or the older [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/optparse.html?highlight=optparse#optparse).

Your script, as it is, should work. Remember to put a shebang line that tells bash to use Python as interpreter, e.g. `#! /usr/bin/env python`